# Posts only showing on /localhost/wordpress/ and not on other pages

Tags: posts, theme-development

I'm following a tutorial on wordpress themes but I've noticed that my posts only appear on the "/localhost/wordpress/" domain and nowhere else, even though they should.

If for example I was to go to "/localhost/wordpress/about-us/" there is not a single post there whilst all the posts shown on "/localhost/wordpress/" should be visible here as well.

The error is not im my theme code, I am 100% sure of that. So my question is, what else can be the cause of this behaviour?

I do **not** use a static home page.

**This is my page.php code**

```
<?php

get_header();

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

     <article class="post page">
         <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
         <?php the_content(); ?>
     </article>

     <?php endwhile;

else :
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

endif;

get_footer();

?>
```

**This is my index.php code**

```
<?php
get_header();

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="post">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile;

else :
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

endif;

get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a shortcode on the about us page or how do you output your posts ?

Posts only appear on your blog page by default.

Do you have a static home page ?

Need some more information here

Comment: I have added the extra information. There are no shortcodes involved as far as I'm aware.